# MongoDB: get all entries with most recent revision

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongo-shell

I'm trying to query a prebuilt MongoDB that keeps revision information around for every entry.  A sample of what the data looks like is this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5cd48bad15447900012fae00"),
  "sku": "abc123",
  "_revision": 5
  "_created": ISODate("2019-05-10T15:00:00.000Z"),
  "provider": "MySupplier5"
}
```

In this example there are entries for the same record with:

- different `_id`
- same `sku`
- same `provider`
- `_revision` set to 1, 2, 3 and 4 (one per document)
- varied `_created` dates

What I want to select is:

> All documents with Provider set of "MySupplier5," but only the most recent revision.

I tried reading the documentation on [Aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) but wasn't able to get what I needed. I felt that the approach I am using to work around it is exceptionally inefficient and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Right now, I am doing this:

1. Get all SKUs:

   `db.products.distinct('sku', { provider: "MySupplier5" }, { _id: 0, sku: 1 })`
2. Loop over all SKUs and get the most recent revision:

   `db.products.find({ sku: 'abc123' }).sort({ revision: -1 }).limit(1)`

That works, but it feels increidbly inefficient.

I was able to get those two queries running using [Mongoid](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/) just fine and I'm sure I could translate whatever is given into the Ruby equivalent as well. I just can't figure out how to say "only give me the most recent revision" in Mongo.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are looking to get the entire document with the max revision, this seems like a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101531/mongo-aggregate-group-max-and-take-entire-row-that-have-the-max-value

Comment: @OlegP - That seems to be what I'm looking for.  I will need to go through it line-by-line and see if I can understand it better and what I was missing in my initial attempts. I'm still extremely new to MongoDB so dissecting queries isn't my strong point at all yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for the answer that I wound up with based on the link provided I am listing it here (apologies for the late, late answer).

It took me all of the following links to be able to learn & figure out exactly what I needed:

- [StackOverflow 55101531](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101531/mongo-aggregate-group-max-and-take-entire-row-that-have-the-max-value)
- [MongoDB Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)
- [MongoDB Aggregation API Doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)
- [Some Samples to drive it home](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_aggregation.htm)

```
[
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$sku",
      "maxRevision": { "$max": "$revision" },
      "originalDocuments": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "originalDocument": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$originalDocuments",
          "as": "doc",
          "cond": {
            "$and": [
              { "$eq": ["abc123", "$$doc.sku"] },
              { "$eq": ["$maxRevision", "$$doc.revision"] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$originalDocument"
  }
]
```